# Code for finding a triangle where the square root of two sides is equal to the square root of third side

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python file for finding there exists a triangle such that sum of squareroot of 2 sides is equal to squareroot of other side which was quoted by 'the Scarecrow' in the Wizard of Oz and more.

But it is not working as expected.It may because it is not efficient.
Please suggest a solution for this.

kindly edit the title and the body if needed

```
import random

num = 1000
a = random.randint(1, num)
b = random.randint(1, num)
c = random.randint(1, num)
x = a + b
y = b + c
z = a + c
k = 0.5
ak = a ** k
bk = b ** k
ck = c ** k
w = 1
while w==1:
        if x>c and y>a and z>b :
                print ("found and verfying")
                if ak+bk == ck:
                        print(a,b,c)
                        w = 2
                else:
                        a = random.randint(1, num)
                        b = random.randint(1, num)
                        c = random.randint(1, num)
                        print(a,b,c," is not a match" )
```

Comment: Edit:sorry I edited "sum of 2 sides is equal to other side" to "sum of squareroot of 2 sides is equal to squareroot of other side" It was my mistake

Comment: I really do recommend this 8 minute Mathologer video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4zqR7GhrqQ Never mind the Simpsons in the title, it is really about the Scarecrow's triangle (quote from the "Wizard of Oz" classic movie at 2:46) and the author is an outstanding mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this one. I change the *if* statement, delete the k and write 0.5 to squareroot them, add *else* if one of the sum less than the side of triangle it stop.

```
import random

num = 1000
a = random.randint(1, num)
b = random.randint(1, num)
c = random.randint(1, num)
x = a + b
y = b + c
z = a + c
ak = a ** 0.5
bk = b ** 0.5
ck = c ** 0.5
w = 1
while w == 1:
    if x > c and y > a and z > b:
        print("found and verfying")
        if ak + bk == ck or ak + ck == bk or bk + ck == ak:
            print(a, b, c, "is verified")
            w = 2
        else:
            a = random.randint(1, num)
            b = random.randint(1, num)
            c = random.randint(1, num)
            print(a, b, c, "is not a match")
    else:
        print("I can't find it")
        w = 2
```

If you want to continue if one of the sum less than the side, you can use this:

```
else:
    print("I can't find it. I am trying new one")
    a = random.randint(1, num)
    b = random.randint(1, num)
    c = random.randint(1, num)
```